# BufferedReader adding weird characters at the start of received message

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

Got a server running independently.

Server code for receiving a message is as follows:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
```

Sending of the message is done by this:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("IpAddress", portNumber);
ClientConnect newConnection = new ClientConnect(clientSocket,StockMarket.getStockMarket());
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
BufferedReader stdln = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while ((userInput = stdln.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println(userInput);
    System.out.println("INPUTED:" + userInput);
    System.out.println("ECHO:    " + stdln.readLine());
}
```

The message is received by the server fine, however it has added chars at the start. For instance if I send "HELP", it will return:

- ��HELP

I've read a bit into the BufferedReader and the InputStreamReader, and I've seen a few times the function: Flush. However I don't understand how to implement it or where.

A nudge in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Remove the ObjectOutputStream, it is not appropriate for text, and you are already wrapping the same stream with a PrintWriter. And specify the encoding for the PrintWriter.

Comment: There isn't a constructor for PrintWriter which takes both the encoding and an OutputStream?

Comment: You are right, not for an OutputStream. `new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true);` (I hesitate to propose also a `new Buffered...`)

Comment: I've added the OutPutStreamWriter to the PrintWriter however it's still adding the characters to the front. Why would the output stream need the UTF-8 if the BufferedReader InputStream has UTF-8 in the construction?

Comment: Did you on both sides add the OutputStreamWriter with UTF-8? And yes, as streams are just bytes, and the information that those bytes are text in some encoding is missing. One always has to provide the charset for bytes.

Comment: Yes I added it to both sides. Still weird chars.

Comment: I would have guessed that ObjectOutputStream was guilty. Unfortunately you should go back, in a new small project, and check which bytes are sent, without Readers and Writers. Delete the string literal, and retype it: there might be a Unicode BOM character (zero-width space) in front of HELP. Then if your editor was set for UTF-8, but your compiler took some Windows ANSI encoding, you would get some similar effect. Last effort would be to restart clean.

Comment: BOM is my guess too. Does this happen only on the first message, or every message? If the first only, somehow the client output charset is UTF-16 and so using a BOM (byte-order mark, to tell the reader if characters are big- or little-endian).